# What's the point of sampling multiple rays per pixel

Tags: random, raytracing, noise-reduction

What is the purpose of multisampled pixels in raytracing? In my experience writing raytracers, there is never any noise, only slight aliasing at lower resolutions, but in most diagrams I see, in the single sampled pixels, there is a ton of noise and black spots. Is this issue noise on single pixels exclusive to global illumination/antialiasing? Or is there another benefit to using multiple samples per pixel?

Answer (score 0):

First of al, images generated by a traditional ray tracers are always affected by noise. The noise mainly originates from calculating the indirect illimitation part of the render equation. Recall the general render equation is:

[image: equation]

Here, the integral part correspond to the indirect illumination and is is solved using [Importance sampling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling). Which requires us to sample multiple rays in random directions at an intersection point `p`. This can be done by:

1. At every intersection branch in several directions to solve the indirect illumination
2. Trace multiple rays per pixel and sample random directions at each intersection point `p`
3. A combination of both.

Now, solving aliasing is traditionally done by sampling random directions with a pixel. Note, that this is not the only way to solve this problem. You can also render a high resolution image and down-scale it afterwards.